# XPages JsonRPC - update ViewScope

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib, json-rpc

I am having troubles setting viewScope from jsonRPC via button (onClick). 
See code below.

I am using a browser (FF/Chrome Mac & PC) to access the XPage. 
After clicking the button i get message "RPC done" as expected, 
but the viewScope is not set.

```
<xe:jsonRpcService id="myRpc" serviceName="myRpcService">
    <xe:this.methods>
        <xe:remoteMethod name="setDialogValues">
            <xe:this.script><![CDATA[var success = false;
try {
viewScope.put("dojoDialog_title", "Window title");
success = true;
} catch (e) {
success = false;
}
return success;]]></xe:this.script>
        </xe:remoteMethod>
    </xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>

<xp:button value="Set viewScope via RPC" id="setVSButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var remoteMethod = myRpcService.setDialogValues();
remoteMethod.addCallback(function(response){
if(response===true){
    alert("RPC done");
}else{
    alert("ERROR");
}
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

EDIT:
What I ultimately want to achieve is setting ViewScope parameters for a dojo dialog. The dialog is opened via CSJS, reads the ViewScope variables and displays the correct page, size and title.

What I have tried successfully is using a label to set ViewScope before opening the dialog. My experience tells me this is a quick and dirty solution that might crash and burn at any time. Surely there must be a better / correct way to set ViewScope or run SSJS before running CSJS?

See code excerpt below.

---

Label - Execute SSJS (Set ViewScope for dialog)

```
<xp:label id="labelSetParamsBeforeOpeningDialog">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var result = '';
try{
if(param.containsKey('runCode')){
if(param.runCode){
    var title = param.title;
    var width = param.width;
    var height = param.height;
    var dialogType = param.dialogType;

    var parentUnid = viewScope.get("currentDocUnid");

    var pageToOpen = "";
    switch(dialogType){
        case "one":
            //Dialog type specific code goes here
            pageToOpen = "dojoDialog_one.xsp?open&parent="+ parentUnid +"&dialog=true";
            break;

        case "two":
            viewScope.put("checkForConflicts", true);
            pageToOpen = 'dojoDialog_two.xsp?open&parent='+ parentUnid;
            break;

        case "three":
            pageToOpen = "dojoDialog_three.xsp?open&parent="+ parentUnid;
            break;

        default:
            pageToOpen = "error-page.xsp?open";
            break;
    }

    viewScope.put('dojoDialog_parentunid', parentUnid);
    viewScope.put('dojoDialog_pageToOpen', pageToOpen);
    viewScope.put('dojoDialog_title', title);
    viewScope.put('dojoDialog_width', width); 
    viewScope.put('dojoDialog_height', height); 
}
}

}catch (e){
    result = "ERROR:"+ e.message;
}

return result;
}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:label>
```

---

Button - Run SSJS (label) then open dialog (CSJS)

```
<xp:button value="Show dialog three" id="myButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
var title = 'THREE';
var width = 1200; 
var height = 440;
var dialogType = 'three';

XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:labelSetParamsBeforeOpeningDialog}",
{
    params: {"runCode":true, "title":title, "width":width, "height":height,"dialogType":dialogType},
onStart: function(){
    //nothing
},
onError: function(){
    alert("ERROR")
},
onComplete: function(){
    XSP.openDialog('#{id:inPlaceDialog}');
}
});]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

---

Dojo dialog - Reads ViewScope

```
<xe:dialog id="inPlaceDialog" style="height:auto;width:auto"
    dojoType="com.ZetaOne.widget.Dialog">
    <xe:this.title>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:var title = 
viewScope.get("dojoDialog_title");return title;}]]>
    </xe:this.title>

    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="autofocus" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>

    <xc:global_dojoDialog_iframe
        elementSRC="#{javascript:applicationScope.dbPath}/#
{javascript:viewScope.dojoDialog_page}"
        elementUnid="#{javascript:viewScope.dojoDialog_unid;}"
        elementParentUnid="#{javascript:viewScope.dojoDialog_parentunid;}"
        elementDialogWidth="#{javascript:viewScope.dojoDialog_width;}"
        elementDialogHeight="#{javascript:viewScope.dojoDialog_height;}">
    </xc:global_dojoDialog_iframe>

    <xp:eventHandler event="onShow" submit="false">
        <xe:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.query("img[aria-label='close 
button']").forEach(function(el){
el.src = "blank_x.gif"; 
});]]></xe:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen JSON RPC is doesn't update the component tree at all. So `viewScope` can't be updated from a JSON RPC call. See http://www.intec.co.uk/json-rpc-service-component-tree-manipulation-openlog/

If you want to update viewScope, I'm not sure why you would use a JSON RPC call over a partial refresh (GET or POST).

Comment: Ok, thanks! How would you suggest I set the viewScope via partial update? I would preferably like to include an attribute to the call: "setDialogParameter(windowName)". I have previously used labels, but found them unreliable.

Comment: This is the code I have tried earlier: XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:labelSetParams}", {
 params: {'$$xspsubmitvalue': null}, 
 onComplete: function(){
  XSP.openDialog('#{id:inPlaceDialog}');
 }
});

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to programmatically affect a Dialog title, I would compute it and use SSJS / Java to display the dialog, which would result in the partial refresh required. If you step back and think about it, SSJS / Java can only run on the server, a dialog can only be displayed on a browser. Using the backend call to display the dialog already has to do what your JavaScript code snippet above does.

Comment: Hi Paul! Thank you for the reply. I have clarified the issue by updating my post.